# What does the given sentence mean? Especially the phrase "I had nothing?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> We were having a conversation, and she asked me where I live, and **I had nothing**.

Does this sentence mean the person reporting the incident couldn't remember or couldn't say anything, or didn't have anything to say?

Comment: I have no idea. Where did you read/hear this?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. It's very difficult to say what the person meant. It's possible they meant 'they couldn't respond because they couldn't think of a good answer' (for example because they were homeless or needed to lie for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

The expression is usually phrased, "I **got** nothing", or "I **'ve got** nothing", or somewhat more formally, "I **have** nothing". In the past, it's only, "I **had** nothing."

"I got nothing" means "I don't have an answer" and it suggests "I think I should have an answer".

The expression is similar to "I'm drawing a blank", but that expression sometimes means that you momentarily forgot, while "I got nothing" means you've thought about it thoroughly, and couldn't come up with anything."

It's also similar to "I have no idea", but that expression sometimes means "I don't know anything about that", whereas with "I got nothing", you think you should have an answer.

Some other contexts where it's commonly heard:

> A: "How are we going to untangle that razor wire?"
> --long pause--
> B: "I got nothing."

> A: "Why are you doing this?"
> --long pause; B just shrugs--
> A: "I'm asking you why you're leaving me, and you've got nothing???"

It sounds like the person in your example sentence has lost their memory, because anyone should know where they live.